# Can you just return a field's hashCode() value in a hashCode() method?

Tags: java, hashcode

While reviewing a large code base, I've often come across cases like this:

```
@Override
public int hashCode() 
{
    return someFieldValue.hashCode();
}
```

where the programmer, instead of generating their own unique hash code for the class, simply inherits the hash code from a field value. My gut feeling (which might just as well be digestive problems) tells me that this is wrong, but I can't put my finger on it. What problems can arise, if any, with this sort of implementation?

Comment: This is actually fine. The only requirement is that two equal object return the same hash. This is the case here.

Comment: Yes, especially for immutable objects. For example, java.lang.String is doing this.

Comment: I found "inherits" to be a jarring choice of word, given that Java has a concept called inheritance which is not involved in this question. I would call this delegation.

Comment: @user11153 `String` is immutable (unless you cheat) but its `hashCode()` is not that of a field as such. The only field that matters (now) is `char[] value` and all arrays use `Object.hashCode()` which is basically identity. `String.hashCode()` instead is computed from the chars *in* the array; see the javadoc.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This is fine if you want to hash your object based on a single property.

For example, in a `Person` class you might have an ID property that uniquely identifies a `Person`, so the `hashCode()` of `Person` can simply be the hash of that ID.

In addition, the `hashCode()` is related to the implementation of `equals`. If two objects are equal, they must have the same `hashCode` (the opposite doesn't have to be true - two non equal objects may still have the same hashCode). Therefore, if equality is determined by a single property (such as a unique ID), the `hashCode` method must also use only that single property.

This can be seen in the JavaDoc of [hashCode](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode%28%29) :

> The general contract of hashCode is:
>
> - Whenever it is invoked on the same object more than once during an execution of a Java application, the hashCode method must consistently return the same integer, provided no information used in equals comparisons on the object is modified. This integer need not remain consistent from one execution of an application to another execution of the same application.
> - If two objects are equal according to the equals(Object) method, then calling the hashCode method on each of the two objects must produce the same integer result.
> - It is not required that if two objects are unequal according to the equals(java.lang.Object) method, then calling the hashCode method on each of the two objects must produce distinct integer results. However, the programmer should be aware that producing distinct integer results for unequal objects may improve the performance of hash tables.

Comment: The way I prefer to phrase the requirement is to say that code which knows that two objects have returned different values for `hashCode()` is entitled to assume that any equality comparison would yield `false`. It's okay for a the hash code of a mutable class object to change when the object is modified *provided that* no cached information about its hash code exists anywhere in the universe. It's often possible for code to meet the latter condition even with mutable types, but unfortunately there's no automated way to enforce the requirement or ensure that it is met.

Answer (score 13):

Technically speaking, you *can* return any consistent number from `hashCode`, even a constant value. The only [requirement the contract places upon you](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode()) is that equal objects must return the same hash code:

> If two objects are equal according to the equals(Object) method, then calling the `hashCode` method on each of the two objects must produce the same integer result.

Theoretically, if all objects return, say, zero for their `hashCode`, the contract is formally satisfied. However, this makes `hashCode` completely useless.

The real question is whether you *should* do it or not. The answer depends on how unique is the field the hash code of which you are returning. It is not uncommon to return the `hashCode` of a unique identifier of an object for the object's `hashCode`. On the other hand, if a significant percentage of objects have the sane value of `someFieldValue`, you would be better off using a different strategy for making the hash code of your object.

Answer (score 3):

`hashCode()` has to go with `equals()`.

If the only property defining equalness is, for example, an ID, you HAVE TO take care that your hash codes are equal when the ID is equal.
The easiest way to accomplish this is by taking the `hashCode()` of your ID.

Answer (score 2):

This is fine, if you really want to uniquely identify your object by this single property. Here is an [article](https://today.java.net/pub/a/today/2006/07/27/defining-object-identity.html) that explains what object identity really is.

As noted in the documentation of [`Object`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29), your `equals()` and `hashCode()` need to incorporate the same properties, be sure to verify that.

So this means that you should ask yourself the question: do I really want the objects to be equal if only this single property is equal?

Finally do take great care when subclassing objects with a custom `equals()` and `hashcode()` implementation, if you want to add properties to the identity of the object, you will break the requirement that `a.equals(b) == b.equals(a)` (to see why this fails thing about this as `a` being the super class and `b` being the subclass.

Answer (score -2):

yes you can do it technically, you need a non-primitive somefieldValue for that.

Comment: Why wouldn't you recommend it?

Comment: It is dependent of application, if you want hashcode of somefieldValue

Comment: Not a useful answer IMO. You're not pointing out possible problems or things to look out for and a large part of this short answer is simply pointing out really basic syntax, which should be easy enough to fix if specifically searched for (and, by the way, wrapper classes for primitives *do* have hash code functions, so this isn't a hard constraint as much as a minor syntactical difference).